# Microsoft Cognitive Services - Authentication Issues, Unable to get Access Token

Tags: android, azure, authentication, http-post, azure-cognitive-services

I am trying to call ms cognitive service from android. However, the api to get access token is not working.. below is the android code

```
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/sts/v1.0/issueToken");


List<NameValuePair> nameValuePair = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", "my subscription key"));

try {
    httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePair));
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {

}

try {
    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

In logcat, i get the error:

`java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "api.cognitive.microsoft.com": No address associated with hostname`

Is there any change to api url "https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/sts/v1.0/issueToken"?

Also, when i type this URL "https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/sts/v1.0/issueToken" in browser, I get the message

```
{ "statusCode": 404, "message": "Resource not found" }
```

Please help.

Comment: On app side regarding "Unable to resolve host "api.cognitive.microsoft.com"" - check firewall/dns. In browser behaviour is correct, as soon as GET does nothing - you should POST there to get a token.

Comment: I verified nothing is blocking the request.. nothing at firewall / dns. Thanks for your suggesions. Any more ideas.

Comment: So it was a typo after all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I known, there is not any change to api url `https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/sts/v1.0/issueToken`, as the same as the content described in the [link](https://www.microsoft.com/cognitive-services/en-us/Speech-api/documentation/API-Reference-REST/BingVoiceRecognition#Authorize).

I tried to call the api via the tool `Postman`[image] and successfully got the token, as below.

You couldn't get the result as your hope via type url in browser, because the api call is a POST request, not a GET request via nagetive a url in browser.

Per your code, seems that the issue was caused by missing the required content length `Content-Length: 0`.

As reference, here is my sample code which works.

```
URL url = new URL("https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/sts/v1.0/issueToken");
HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.setRequestProperty("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", "XXXXXXXX");
conn.setRequestMethod("POST"); 
conn.setDoOutput(true); // Must set do output true
conn.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(0); // Set Content-Length 0
conn.connect();
int code = conn.getResponseCode();
String msg = conn.getResponseMessage();
System.out.println(code+"\t"+msg);
IOUtils.copy(conn.getInputStream(), System.out);
```

The response as below for the above code.

```
200 OK
eyXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

Comment: I tried the code shared by you and I get the error: "12-21 17:18:33.063: W/System.err(5372): java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "api.cognitive.microsoft.com": No address associated with hostname
"

Comment: Pan - My bad, there was a typo. Your solution is working perfectly. Many thanks for detailed explanation. Appreciated.